# INFORMIX-SE for Windows with 4Js Genero Client

Tags: informix

OK, so I recently downloaded 4J's Genero Studio 90-day trial version. I would like to use INFORMIX-SE for the backend with Genero's client. Is INFORMIX-SE for Windows available on a trial version?.. I see that IDS is available as a free download, but IDS would be an overkill for my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the ['downloads'](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/informix/downloads.html) page (Google search terms '*site:ibm.com informix standard engine*').  You have to contact your IBM sales representative to obtain a trial or demo version of Informix SE.

Comment: OK, so I visited IBM's informix trial downloads and confirm your answer about SE. Some time ago, I had seen that IDS express edition was available as a free download. Now it seems that offer has disappeared, so neither SE and IDS servers are available for free, which I feel is a factor in my decision as to whether I will package my app with an Informix engine vs. MySQL or SQL-Server which are available for free.

Comment: @Frank: Express Edition no longer exists - there is a new set of edition names.  The web page I pointed you to has free downloads of Informix Developer Edition and Informix Innovator-C Edition - both versions of IDS, with slightly different rules on what you're allowed to do with them.